# git actions demo workflow on windows fails to parse

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

[github has a workflow yaml file they suggest you use as an introduction to git actions.](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/quickstart) In that yaml file is the following line:

```
- run: echo " The name of your branch is ${{ github.ref }} and your repository is ${{ github.repository }}."
```

When the workflow job is executed the  gets converted into ðŸ”Ž which as you can see has a double quote in it. This eventually causes a parsing error and the job fails to execute. I find it really hard to believe that the workflow file they give you as an introduction to their product would fail right out of the box. Is there something in the environment or in my setup that I would have missed that would have prevented this situation?

Throwing another double quote at the end fixes the situation but that just seems silly.

```
- run: echo " The name of your branch is ${{ github.ref }} and your repository is ${{ github.repository }}.""
```

Comment: Are you able to share where you got this introduction workflow from?

Comment: @tj-cappelletti I edited the post to include a link to the quickstart guide

Comment: What is the file encoding that you're using? With UTF-8, it works as expected. No extra quotes needed. Did you change the runner or its default shell?

Comment: @Azeem I did not explicitly request any particular encoding. The workflow in this case is running on a self hosted windows PC. When I look at the raw text log for the failed job it shows that it is using powershell (WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.EXE)

Comment: Check the encoding of your workflow file e.g. by using VS Code or Notepad or some other way. GHA hosted Windows runner has Powershell as the default shell. So, shell doesn't seem to be an issue here. Looks like that fixing the file encoding to UTF-8 should fix this. You may try adding another test workflow too.

Comment: @Azeem I copied the text from the github link using the copy button on the top right of the code box. I then pasted the contents into a blank notepad window and saved it as a .yml with UTF-8 selected. I uploaded it to github and the workflow blows up in the same spot.... so very strange!

Comment: Strange, indeed. I don't have a Windows machine at the moment otherwise I would test it with Notepad. I tested with VS Code and it worked fine. You may try using VS Code.